# ModuleNotFoundError: インストール済のalpha_vantageパッケージが見つからない？

Tags: python, python3

## 状況

[alpha_vantage](https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage)モジュールがインストールされているにも関わらず、`ModuleNotFoundError`が発生してしまいます。

### 実行環境

仮想環境(venv)上で実行しております。
インタプリタも仮想環境のもの`./.vevn/bin/python`を使用しています。

そして、このように`alpha-vantage`は仮想環境にインストール済みです。

```
$ which python
/home/****/***/***/.venv/bin/python

$ which pip
/home/****/***/***/.venv/bin/pip

$ pip freeze | grep alpha
alpha-vantage==2.3.1
```

### 実行コード

```py
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from pprint import pprint
ts = TimeSeries(key='********', output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='MSFT',interval='1min', outputsize='full')
pprint(data.head(2))
```

### 実行結果

```
python alpha_vantage.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/***/***/***/alpha_vantage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
  File "/home/***/***/***/alpha_vantage.py", line 1, in <module>
    from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'alpha_vantage.timeseries'; 'alpha_vantage' is not a package
```

念の為、仮想環境上だけでなく本体の方にも`alpha_vantage`モジュールをインストールして実行してみましたが、結果は同じく`ModuleNotFoundError`でした。

どうか解決方法があれば教えてください。

Comment: この記事を参考にモジュール検索パスを確認してみてはどうでしょう？ [Pythonでimportの対象ディレクトリのパスを確認・追加（sys.pathなど）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-import-module-search-path/)

Comment: @kunif  `pprint.pprint(sys.path)`こちらのコマンドでモジュール検索パスを調べてみたのですが、`/home/***/***/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages'`が見つかりました。ということは、`alpha_vantage`パッケージは発見されるのが正常な動作ではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

## 原因

実行したファイル名がモジュール名と同じであったから。

実行ファイル名: alpha_vantage.py
インポートしたいパッケージ: alpha_vantage

## 解決策

実行ファイル名を変更する。
alpha_vantage.py -> **alp_vantage**.py

これで実行ファイル名がモジュール名と被ることがなくなり、正常にパッケージを読み込むことができる。

## 参考

https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage/issues/64#issuecomment-384323361